# replace some column values from a data.frame based on another data.frame

Tags: r

I have two data.frames, (df1, df2) and I would like to replace the values in columns P1-P10 the letters with the values of `df1$V2` but keeping the first two columns of df2.

```
df1 = data.frame(V1=LETTERS, V2=rnorm(26))

df2 <- data.frame(Name=sample(LETTERS, 6), bd=sample(1:6), P1=sample(LETTERS,6), P2=sample(LETTERS, 6), P3=sample(LETTERS, 6), P4=sample(LETTERS, 6), P5=sample(LETTERS, 6), P6=sample(LETTERS, 6), P7=sample(LETTERS, 6), P8=sample(LETTERS, 6), P9=sample(LETTERS, 6), P10=sample(LETTERS, 6))
```

My approach is the following:

```
df3 <- matrix(setNames(df1[,2], df1[,1])[as.character(unlist(df2[,3:12]))], nrow=6, ncol=10)
df4 <- data.frame(cbind(df2[,1:2], df3))
```

Which gives me my desire output, my real data has 10,000 columns, is there any way to avoid the `cbind` step or make the process fast?

```
> df4
Name bd         X1          X2         X3         X4         X5         X6        X7         X8         X9        X10
1    V  6 -1.8991102  0.40269050 -0.1517500 -2.5297829  1.5315622  1.4897071  1.364071 -1.2443708 -1.3197276 -0.4917057
2    T  1 -2.5297829 -0.44614123 -0.1894970 -0.6693774 -0.1517500 -1.0650962 -0.151750 -0.4461412 -0.6693774 -1.1351770
3    R  5 -0.6693774  0.09059365 -2.5297829  0.3233827 -0.9383348 -0.4461412  1.281797  1.5315622  1.4897071 -0.4461412
4    B  4 -0.4461412 -0.93833476 -1.2443708 -0.4461412 -0.1894970 -0.9383348 -1.135177 -1.8991102 -0.1894970  0.4026905
5    K  2 -1.0180271 -1.06509624 -0.1939600 -0.1894970  1.4897071 -0.6693774 -1.899110 -1.3197276  1.5315622 -0.1517500
6    Y  3  1.5315622 -0.19396005 -0.4917057 -0.4664239 -1.8991102  0.4026905 -1.065096 -0.9383348 -1.2443708 -0.4664239
```

Thanks

Comment: In your example P1-P10 are factors. Is it really so in your dataset?

Comment: yes, they are factors in my dataset,sorry for my late reply

Comment: OK, my answer now works with factors as well as characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `match` the values of `df2[3:12]` in `df1[[1]]`. These row numbers are used to extract the values from `df1[2]`.

```
df2[3:12] <- df1[match(as.character(unlist(df2[3:12])), 
                       as.character(df1[[1]])), 2]
```

The result (`df2`):

```
  Name bd         P1         P2         P3         P4         P5         P6         P7         P8         P9        P10
1    H  5  0.1199355  0.3752010 -0.3926061 -1.1039548 -0.1107821  0.9867373 -0.3360094 -0.7488000 -0.3926061  2.0667704
2    U  4  0.1168599  0.1168599  0.9867373  1.3521418  0.9867373 -0.3360094 -0.7724007 -0.3926061 -0.3360094 -1.2543480
3    R  3 -1.2337890 -0.1107821 -0.7724007  2.0667704  0.3752010  0.4645504  0.9867373  0.1168599 -0.0981773 -0.3926061
4    G  2 -0.3926061  0.3199261 -0.0981773 -0.1107821  2.0667704 -1.1039548 -1.2337890  0.3199261 -1.2337890 -2.1534678
5    C  6 -2.1534678 -1.1039548 -1.1039548 -0.7488000  0.4645504  0.3199261 -2.1534678 -0.3360094  0.9867373  0.8771467
6    I  1  0.6171634  0.6224091  1.8011711  0.7292998  0.8771467  2.0667704  0.3752010  0.4645504 -2.1534678 -0.7724007
```

If you don't want to replace the values inside `df2`, you can create a new data frame `df4` with

```
df4 <- "[<-"(df2, 3:12, value = df1[match(as.character(unlist(df2[3:12])), 
                                          as.character(df1[[1]])), 2])
```

Comment: Hello again @Sven Hohensein, something weird is happening with my data, I have converted my data.frame to a matrix for speed the calculations (7 rows, 10,000 columns). When I apply your solution, the values are replaced only until a certain number of columns, for example, from 1220 the values are not replaced keeping the "character" value. The dput of my data is too big for posting here but I'd like to ask for your help. Many thanks

Comment: @user2380782 In my code, `3:12` represents the numbers of the columns of interest. Maybe you should try with `3:10000` instead.

Comment: @user2380782 Did you replace both `3:12` with `3:dim(df)[2]`?

Comment: Yes, I did. It is a little weird... I'll try to figure out what is happening

Comment: Hello @Sven Hohenstein, the problem was that when I converted the `data.frame` to a `matrix` I forgot that the structure is different, so I should add `df1[match(as.character(unlist(df2[,3:12])`. A `,` makes a big difference...

Comment: Could you tell me how to create a new `matrix` instead of a `data.frame` in the same way you did for `df4 <- "[<-"(df2, ...` when my data was a `data.frame`? Thanks a lot

Comment: @user2380782 Just create the data frame and then use `as.matrix(df4)`.

Comment: The answers here do not reflect the initial question anymore. If you want to work with matrices you should modify your question accordingly or make another question.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Hey, I'm using this code for a smilar thing, the problem that I have is that when the character is not presented in `df1` then I get replacement of NA's in `df2`. what can I do if I don't want this to happen? I just want the original character in `df2`!
Thanks

Comment: @mahmood You can create a data frame `newdf` with these commands: `newdf <- df2;
newdf[3:12] <- df1[match(as.character(unlist(df2[3:12])), 
                         as.character(df1[[1]])), 2];
idx <- is.na(newdf);
newdf[idx] <- df2[idx]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try some `*pply` magic:

```
lookup<-tapply(df1$V2, df1$V1, unique) #Creates a lookup table
lookup.function<-function(x) as.numeric(lookup[as.character(x)]) #The function
df4<-data.frame(df2[,1:2], apply(df2[,3:12], 2,lookup.function )) #Builds the output
```

**Update**:

The `*pply` family is much faster than `merge`, at least an order of magnitude. Check this out

```
num<-1000
df1 = data.frame(V1=LETTERS, V2=rnorm(26))
df2<-data.frame(cbind(first=1:num,second=1:num, matrix(sample(LETTERS, num^2, replace=T), nrow=num, ncol=num)))


start<-Sys.time()
lookup<-tapply(df1$V2, df1$V1, unique)
lookup.function<-function(x) as.numeric(lookup[as.character(x)])
df4<-data.frame(cbind(df2[,1:2], data.frame(apply(df2[,3:(num+2)], 2, lookup.function ))))
(difftime(Sys.time(),start))


start<-Sys.time()
df4.merge <- "[<-"(df2, 3:num, value = df1[match(as.character(unlist(df2[3:num])), as.character(df1[[1]])), 2])
(difftime(Sys.time(),start))

sum(df4==df4.merge)==num^2
```

For 3000 columns and rows the `*pply` combination needs 4.3s whereas `merge` needs about 22s on my slow Intel. And it scales nicely. For 4000 columns and rows the respective times are 7.4 sec and 118 sec.

Comment: If I converted the data.frames, (now I have a list of data.frames that I would like to match against a single data.frame) to a matrix class for speeding calculations, could I adapt your approach? Thanks @ECII

Comment: Why do you have to convert anything? Whats wrong with my approach? You have to give us reproducible examples

Comment: I've converted the data.frame to a matrix because it comes from a previous step involving sampling in my list of data.frames and every iteration with lapply is slow in data.frames compared to matrices. I have not posted my problem including the list of data.frames because I thought it would be more understandable just summarising a list of data.frames into a data.frame but it was a mistake. But there is nothing wrong with your approach, just asking if I could implement it on matrices. Thanks for your quick reply

Comment: You say you have data frames of 6 rows and 10.000 columns. My answer should take less than a second to match. What do you need more?

Comment: hi @ECII your approach is really fast, and it worked really well. However I am trying to apply it for running in a list a matrices against a data.frame and it takes so long, could be because the `lapply`? thanks

Comment: i imagine it would be possible to modify it so that it works with lists and matrices.